# Granting PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION access right to an IIS worker process in Windows - without making it an Administrator

Tags: windows, winapi

Is there a user-friendly way to grant a PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION access right to a web site which runs under IIS? Like adding the application pool’s user to a certain local group, etc. - but without making it an Administrator.

Background: my web site will be deployed to customer's machines, and I'm wondering if there's a way to grant it limited access rights to other processes running on the machine - but without requiring Administrator privileges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no realistic way to do this as described - you would need to change the permissions assigned to new processes.  That's not technically impossible, but it would be a very intrusive change, and certainly can't be done without some code running with administrator or higher privileges.

I've just checked the permissions on a few of the processes running on my machine (using [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx)) and they typically grant access only to the local system account and the user that is running the process.  Sadly, there is no "query process information" group in the default process ACL.

What you *could* do, however, is to have a second component that runs as local system and provides the main component with the necessary information.  Separating the functionality makes this a much safer approach than running your web site itself with administrator privilege.  The second component needn't be running under IIS, it could be a system service, and if the functionality it provides isn't absolutely essential you could even make it an optional add-on.

Depending on your precise needs, I would suggest shared memory as the most appropriate IPC mechanism (giving the web site account read-only access) combined with a named mutex object to prevent torn reads.  That way, the privileged process isn't reading anything from the non-privileged process, significantly reducing any possible exposure if the non-privileged process is compromised.